# Кодировка в Массиве

Tags: java, android, json

Проблема в том, что я отправляю `JSON` в базу, а там вместо кирилицы Знаки вопроса.

У меня типа так:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    arraylist.add("first");
    arraylist.add("second");
    arraylist.add("third");
    arraylist.add("fourth");
```

Потом **преобразовываю** `ArrayList` в `Json`

```
String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(arrayList);
```

**Отправляю:**

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Application.TEST_API);
List<NameValuePair> valuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
valuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("request", "SAVE_RESULT"));
valuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("result", jsonString));

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(valuePairs));
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

**Вопрос:**

1) Как Преобразовать в `jsonString` мой массив в кодировке `UTF-8`?

2) Или проблема при отправке, где `httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(valuePairs))`, так как, `UrlEncodedFormEntity()`

```
public UrlEncodedFormEntity(List<? extends NameValuePair> parameters) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        this(parameters, "ISO-8859-1");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Крайне рекомендую использовать готовые решения - например Retrofit (де-факто стандард для работы с веб сервисами).

Например они делают так - используя jSonWriter:
https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit-converters/gson/src/main/java/retrofit2/converter/gson/GsonRequestBodyConverter.java

```
  @Override public RequestBody convert(T value) throws IOException {
    Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
    Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(buffer.outputStream(), UTF_8);
    JsonWriter jsonWriter = gson.newJsonWriter(writer);
    adapter.write(jsonWriter, value);
    jsonWriter.close();
    return RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE, buffer.readByteString());
  }
```

Comment: Пока времени нет на изучение. Что скажете по моему вопросу?